# syntax error near unexpected token ; in one liner

Tags: bash

I am really new to bash scripting and I am learning as I go. I have a script that I made into a one liner

```
after=d_20141123_0437; before=d_20141124_0440; for a in $(hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/directory/d_2014112* | grep -oE '/(.*)') ; do ; if { test "$a" \> "$after" && test "$a" \> "$before" ; } || ; test "$a" = "$after" || test "$a" = "$before" ; then ; echo "$a" ; if ; done
```

Here is the command before it has been converted to a one liner:

```
after=d_20141123_0437
before=d_20141124_0440
for a in * ; do
    if { test "$a" \> "$after" && test "$a" \< "$before" ; } ||
            test "$a" = "$after" || test "$a" = "$before" ; then
        echo "$a"
    fi
done
```

I tried running this command but I get the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

I can't seem to figure out how to solve this issue because I am new to bash scripting. I was wondering if someone could be another pair of eyes to help my fix this error

Comment: Remove the `;` after the `do` clause.

Comment: Where do several `||` come from? I cannot find them in the original script. Revise your code-in-just-one-line: it is not equivalent to the second script.

Comment: @Jdamian my mistake. fixed!

Comment: You have a different if-test in the 'one-liner' than in the multi-line script.

Comment: remove `;` after `||`

Comment: @Jdamian i removed the `;` after the do and also after the second `||` still getting the same error =/

Comment: You can't have a `;` immediately after the `then` either.

Comment: Basically -- only add `;`s in places where a split between commands is required by syntax, not in every single place where you're replacing a newline.

Comment: I guess the last `if` is actually a `fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in BASH:

```
after=d_20141123_0437; before=d_20141124_0440; while read -r a; do if { test "$a" \> "$after" && test "$a" \> "$before" ; } || test "$a" = "$after" || test "$a" = "$before"; then echo "$a"; fi ; done < <(hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/directory/d_2014112* | grep -oE '/(.*)')
```

Comment: I get this error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'`

Comment: I cannot test since I don't have `hadoop`. You can insert `echo "$a";` after `do` to see what it prints.

Answer (score 1):

When I took a look at the one-liner, simply splitting on spaces, you have different logic than the multi-line version.  Specifically, your testing for the filename ($a) being 'between' $before and $after differs,

```
after=d_20141123_0437;
before=d_20141124_0440; 
for a in $(hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/directory/d_2014112* | grep -oE '/(.*)') ; do
    ;
    if { test "$a" \> "$after" && test "$a" \> "$before" ; } || ; test "$a" = "$after" || test "$a" = "$before" ; then ; 
        echo "$a" ;
    if ;
done
```

Specifically, there is a ';' (semicolon) before the second occurence of 'test'.

You might rewrite this test as,

```
    if [ "$a" \< "$before" ] ; then next; fi
    if [ "$a" \> "$after"  ] ; then next; fi
    echo "$a" ;
```

Comment: I guess the last `if` is actually a `fi`

Comment: Note that the one-liner, as provided by the poster, was an "if", which is also a syntax error.  But correct, it should be a "fi".